# GCM To FCM Migration For Push Notification Android

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am Migrating From GCM to FCM FOR SENDING Push notification to my some Android application of my Organization.

I have changed the GCM End Point to FCM End Point at Server Level.

I want to know Two Things related to this Migration -
1) when gcm api will depreciated after 11 april , 2019, Do i need to change my existing Project From Google Console to FCM Console or There is no need to change existing project from Google Console.

2)Do we need to change any code at application level (Client Side) for getting Push notification because we have used FCM End Point URL in place of GCM Url (Keeping rest of code logic same) at server end .

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you read the guidelines specified on how to [Migrate a GCM Client App for Android to Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm#switch-to-fcm-in-the-app-level-buildgradle)?

Comment: Yes I have read it .I have changed End point url from GCM to FCM  at server end & tested notification are delivered at andriod application which still has gcm logic at code level (I have not changed at any thing on Google Console & Application End). NOW I HAVE CONCERNED WHAT WILL HAPPEN AFTER 11 APRIL , 2019  ...  , it will keep on working or not .